# KMZ vector file over Google Maps

Tags: google-maps

I have a KMZ vector file which works fine on my Google Earth application, but I want to overlay this on my phone (android) through Google Maps.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 5):

Not sure if this is quite what you are getting at, but you can view any KMZ (as long as it is under the size limit, not quite sure what that is...) in google maps by referencing its location it in the google maps url:

https://maps.google.com/maps?q=http://geomaps.wr.usgs.gov/sfgeo/geologic/docs/San_Francisco_County.kmz

you can place the url to any kml or kmz after "maps?q=" to view it in google maps (or if you are using the standard google maps search interface, just enter the url to your kml/kmz into the search bar)

This displays the USGS kmz of San Francisco geology in google maps.  It works on my iPhone, let me know if this works for your Android.

Answer (score 2):

**Google Earth for Android** devices is available for Free from Google Play Store

This will display your KML/KMZ files.

Currently on version 7.0.1

```
New in 7.0.1:
* Bug fixes
New in 7.0:
* Tour guide: Explore places you never thought to search for with new tours of your favorite cities, historic landmarks and natural wonders.
* 3D imagery: Take flight above entire cities in 3D. Get started with Los Angeles, Boston, San Francisco, Geneva or Rome and look for new additions in the coming weeks. Available for devices with dual-core processors.
```

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.earth

Just be careful on data usage limits on your Mobile/Cell plan